# Google Ads - Is the campaign_criterion.criterion_id the same as geographic_view.country_criterion_id?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

Just like the title, I am migrating from Adwords to Google Ads. I want to know the Total Google Ads Cost (365 days) based on the country name.

Hence, I need to know whether the criterion_id from campaign_criterion is the same as the country_criterion_id from the geographic_view.

Moreover, I was able to get access to geoTargetConstants using REST but could not find any document that could help me get access to geographic_view.

[This is geoTargetConstants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s35vr.png)

Any methods to get access to geographic_view using Postman?

Comment: Please include your code